Did Biden ever officially state he would be a one term president?
I have seen this go around a lot on online forums (example link, link, many more can be found in similar politics forums). Lots of people are claiming if Biden had kept his promise of being a one term president the Democratic Party would have done much better in the election, and he took too long to back out of the race, leaving Harris or even the Democratic Party only a few weeks to prepare. Many are claiming if he had only stayed committed to being a one term president as he promised there would probably have been a better candidate than Harris.
I cannot find any credible source for this. In fact I think the first time I even heard about this was after he backed out of the election, when people started posting online about how he should have backed out earlier as promised, giving the party enough time for a primary.
Did he officially state he would be a one term president before or after he got elected? Is there any proper source verifying or denying this?

See Has President Joe Biden made any public statements on wanting to run for a second term?. One term was denied about two months after taking office.

@RickSmith thank you, very useful link. So in fact the opposite was true. Then I don't understand why this claim of him wanting to be a one term president is so popular online right now.

This is a repost of a skepitcs question https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57488/did-biden-ever-officially-state-he-would-be-a-one-term-president?noredirect=1#comment282722_57488

Cross-posted on skeptics.se we ask that you don't clutter the network with duplicates.

@user17915, that Biden made a different claim at one point does not establish that he did not make the claim you ask about at another point, before or since.  And even if he didn't, many people got the impression during his 2020 campaign that he planned to serve only a single term, and it seems unlikely that that was accidental.  It may have been his sincere intent at one point, or the desire and expectation of his party, or it may have been merely a political strategem to spread that idea.  Either way, people criticizing the seeming flip flop are not wholly unjustified.

A big problem for Harris was not only having "only a few weeks to prepare". She was even seen by many as the de facto president (rightly or wrongly) besides what they saw as a barely functional Biden. A big problem for her was that she became a candidate without anyone actually voting for her. This might not bother you, but it likely did bother a lot of people who saw this as contrary to the values of a democratic system, or something suspicious and sinister. Many mentioned an internal coup within the party, or a deliberate charade, and right or wrong, it did affect their decision.

@vsz the question is not about who is or is not a good candidate though. I'm sorry if it comes across as such to you, but this is intended to be a completely neutral post. I have been hearing about claims, since Biden stepped down, that he stated he was going to be a 1 term president when he got elected. I've seen many such claims on forum comments and youtube videos where someone just casually mentions it, but I don't think I've ever seen anything official about it

To repeat the relevant context bit from the related Q, it was reported in Dec 2019:

Underscoring the single-term assumption was reporting like this from Ryan Lizza in Politico early in the campaign: “According to four people who regularly talk to Biden, all of whom asked for anonymity to discuss internal campaign matters, it is virtually inconceivable that he will run for reelection in 2024.”

So, not officially, but quasi-official 'leaks' from his entourage, AFAICT.

So its all speculation then. I think the people online are just looking for something to blame the result on

@user17915: sometimes campaigns will officially deny some stuff that gets rumoured or claimed by someone associated. (E.g. recently https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2024/11/10/trump-team-dismisses-republican-strategists-ukraine-peace-plan-claim) That didn't happen then in this Biden case.

@user17915 Not exactly, this sounds more like something the campaign wanted to imply while still keeping it at arm's length. Biden could have contradicted it publicly and explicitly. Doing it after two months in office is very conspicuous. He didn't do it during the campaign when it could have hurt him but felt the need to declare his intent to run for a second term much earlier than usual, implicitly acknowledging that he wasn't expected to do it.

An article from The Hill says,

So Biden never explicitly made a one-term promise during the campaign, but he certainly implied it with the language of “transition.”


“Transition president” is such an equivocal term that it is not a commitment to or even a clear implication of anything.
